# How to retrieve response data from xhrpost function and store that object in dojo/store?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've created a login with [REST](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/rest.html) and [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store.html). I'm submitting my login form data with [dojo xhrpost](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr). The submit is executed via onClick function. Responses are returned from rest methods. How do I store the response object in a dojo/store such as [dojo/Memory](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Memory.html)? That way I can retrieve it in any html page and delete the objects for logout.

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/userservices/rest/rest/login",
    form: dojo.byId("formNode"),
    load: function(user,status) {

        if(status.xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(user); //---> which displays username from the response method in rest method
            // What code for could be here for storing that user as an object to dojo store or memory to access several pages and delete the object?
            window.location.href ="jobseekerdashboard.html";                                                
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

dojo.xhrPost is deprecated. Have a look at [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr).

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/store/Memory"], function(xhr, Memory){
  xhr("http://localhost:8080/userservices/rest/rest/login", {
    method: "POST",
    data: dojo.byId("formNode")
  }).then(function(returnedData){
    new Memory({
      data: returnedData
    });
    window.location.href= "jobseekerdashboard.html";
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  }
});
```

If you change the window location though, you will lose the current enviroment. If you want to change the page location you will have to make a new ajax request once that page loads or you will have to pass the data in the session data.